# Combining/Summing rows of a numy array based on a list of indices

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have an array where I would like to add specific rows together in order to get an array with less rows.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
b = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]
a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34],
       [35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])

a.shape
(10, 5)

len(b)
10
```

I want to use `b` as the basis for the rows I'd like to combine. The first 3 rows would be summed to become the new 1st row, the 4th and 5th rows would be summed to become the new 2nd row. And so on and so forth.

Desired result:

```
array([[15, 18, 21, 24, 27],
       [35, 37, 39, 41, 43],
       [130, 134, 138, 142, 146],
       [45, 46, 47, 48, 49]])
```

Looping would be inefficient for my purpse. I'm not sure if this could be done in numpy, but perhaps pandas or xarray?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pandas solution is create `DataFrame` and aggregate sum by index created by `b` array:

```
a = np.arange(50).reshape(10, 5)
b = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]
print (a)

c = pd.DataFrame(a, index=b).sum(level=0).to_numpy()
print (c)
[[ 15  18  21  24  27]
 [ 35  37  39  41  43]
 [130 134 138 142 146]
 [ 45  46  47  48  49]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)
b = [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2,3]

sum_common = lambda x : sum(a[b==x,:])

indx = np.unique(b)

c = np.array(map(sum_common, indx))
```

Of course it can be done in one line:

```
c=np.array(map(lambda x : sum(a[b==x,:]), np.unique(b)))
```

The result:

```
array([[ 15,  18,  21,  24,  27],
       [ 35,  37,  39,  41,  43],
       [130, 134, 138, 142, 146],
       [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49]])
```